# How to remove empty space while using load Jquery?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am loading one html page(having image in center) into another page using following command.

```
 $(function(){
      $("#section").load("image.html"); 
  });

 <div id="section" style="min-width: 400px; height: 400px; max-width: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
```

But i found image gets included but it does not fit compeletely in section as there are empty spaces around image. How can i remove empty space?

Comment: Make the image a bit bigger, div a bit smaller, what have you tried?

Comment: Would you be able to link to source?

Comment: Are you talking about transparent or white pixels in the image itself, or margin/padding around the `<img>` element?

Comment: margin/padding around the image.

Answer (score 1):

from http://api.jquery.com/load/:
The .load() method, unlike $.get(), allows us to specify a portion of the remote document to be inserted. This is achieved with a special syntax for the url parameter. If one or more space characters are included in the string, the portion of the string following the first space is assumed to be a jQuery selector that determines the content to be loaded.

so you can try to load like that:

```
$("#section").load("image.html img");
```

this will load only all `<img>` tags from image.html

of course, this may not work, if there's more content, you want to show. then you should try to restyle image.html - to remove padding, margin etc.

as long, as you can specify the content of image.html you should ask yourself, why you want to include this, instead of just load the picture itself.

Comment: Another way you could style the body tag of the image.html to have no magin or padding.

Comment: It is important that the selector in the load method be unique. Else you'll run into problems

Comment: @kranthi117 why? i do this with my page - and my load selects for .contentContainer - this returns all divs with the specified class, without problems...

Comment: glad to hear that - feared to run into a problem on my page... would have had deep impact ;)